# Decrease bazel memory usage

Tags: bazel

I'm using bazel on a computer with 4 GB RAM (to compile the tensorflow project). Bazel does however not take into account the amount of memory I have and spawns too many jobs causing my machine to swap and leading to a longer build time.

I already tried setting [the ram_utilization_factor flag](http://bazel.io/docs/bazel-user-manual.html#flag--ram_utilization_factor) through the following lines in my `~/.bazelrc`

```
build --ram_utilization_factor 30
test --ram_utilization_factor 30
```

but that did not help. How are these factors to be understood anyway? Should I just randomly try out some others?

Comment: Related (how to increase heap memory given to Bazel so it can build without out-of-memory errors): [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when running bazel build](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55190272/4561887). I have a [thorough answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60572662/4561887) there.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Some other flags that might help:

- `--host_jvm_args` can be used to set how much memory the JVM should use by setting `-Xms` and/or `-Xmx`, e.g., `bazel --host_jvm_args=-Xmx4g --host_jvm_args=-Xms512m build //foo:bar` ([docs](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--host_jvm_args)).
- `--local_resources` in conjunction with the `--ram_utilization_factor` flag ([docs](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--local_resources)).
- `--jobs=10` (or some other low number, it defaults to 200), e.g. `bazel build --jobs=2 //foo:bar` ([docs](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--jobs)).

Note that `--host_jvm_args` is a *startup option* so it goes *before* the command (`build`) and `--jobs` is a "normal" build option so it goes *after* the command.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Nothing worked but setting `--jobs` manually to some low number, which I wanted to avoid initially.

Comment: Same here. JVM arguments didn't give any effect, `--jobs` made it work.

Comment: In case anyone has the opposite problem and needs to give Bazel _more_ memory to build, but you don't have enough RAM to do so, you can increase your virtual memory instead and then increase the `Xmx` value. [I explain how to do this on Linux here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60572662/4561887)

Answer (score 4):

For me, the `--jobs` argument from @kristina's answer worked:

```
bazel build --jobs=1 tensorflow:libtensorflow_all.so
```

**Note:** `--jobs=1` must follow, not precede `build`, otherwise bazel will not recognize it. If you were to type `bazel --jobs=1 build tensorflow:libtensorflow_all.so`, you would get this error message:

```
Unknown Bazel startup option: '--jobs=1'.
```

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to second @sashoalm's comment that the `--jobs=1` flag was what made bazel build finally work.

For reference, I'm running bazel on Lubuntu 17.04, running as a VirtualBox guest with about 1.5 GB RAM and two cores of an Intel i3 (I'm running a Thinkpad T460).  I was following the O'Reilly tutorial on TensorFlow (https://www.oreilly.com/learning/dive-into-tensorflow-with-linux), and ran into trouble at the following step:

`$ bazel build tensorflow/examples/label_image:label_image`

Changing this to `bazel build --jobs=1 tensorflow/...` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

i ran into quite a few unstability that bazel build failed in my k8s cluster.

Besides `--jobs=1`, try this:
https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#flag--local_resources
E.g. `--local_resources=4096,2.0,1.0`